# JavaFX - How do I add an "image" layered on top of a scene?

Tags: java, javafx, graphics

I'm making a 2D game with JavaFX. There is a background which is set as the game scene.

How do I add an image which will act as a "tank" that can operated by a player to move and shoot, which will be layered on top of a scene (with the background)?

It is worth noting that the tank will have a x,y and rotation parameters. Then collisions will be applied to the tank, in which it can also fire bullets.

This is running on Eclipse IDE and JavaFX. I've tried adding another method to my `ViewManager` and call the method from the `ViewManager` constructor. I've also added a scene in `Main.java` so that both scenes can be shown.

This is from `Main.java`

```
import javafx.application.Application; //import JavaFX libraries
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        try
        {
            ViewManager manager = new ViewManager();
            primaryStage = manager.getMainStage();
            primaryStage.setScene(manager.drawImageOnScreen(50, 50, 0, "image path"));
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//end catch
    }//end start

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }//end main
}//end class
```

This is my `ViewManager.java` that attempts to add the image on top of a scene.

```
/* I've discarded the imported libraries and packages*/

public class ViewManager {

    private static final int HEIGHT = 1000;
    private static final int WIDTH = 1366;
    private AnchorPane mainPane;
    private Scene mainScene;
    private Stage mainStage;

    private final static int GAME_BUTTON_START_X = 100;
    private final static int GAME_BUTTON_START_Y = 150;

    List<WarstrikeButton> gameButtons;

    public ViewManager()
    {
        //Initialize the game stage
        initializeStage();

        //Initialize the game buttons
        gameButtons = new ArrayList<>();
        createButtons();

        //Create background
        createBackground();

    }//end viewManager

    private void initializeStage() {
        mainPane = new AnchorPane();
        mainScene = new Scene(mainPane, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        mainStage = new Stage();
        mainStage.setScene(mainScene);
    }

    public Stage getMainStage()
    {
        return mainStage;
    }

    private void addGameButton(WarstrikeButton button)
    {
        button.setLayoutX(GAME_BUTTON_START_X);
        button.setLayoutY(GAME_BUTTON_START_Y + gameButtons.size() * 100);
        gameButtons.add(button);
        mainPane.getChildren().add(button);
    }

    private void createButtons()
    {

        createMoveButton();
        createShootButton();

    }//end createButtons method

    private void createMoveButton()
    {
        WarstrikeButton moveButton = new WarstrikeButton("Move");
        addGameButton(moveButton);
    }

    private void createShootButton()
    {
        WarstrikeButton shootButton = new WarstrikeButton("Shoot");
        addGameButton(shootButton);
    }

    private void createBackground()
    {
        Image backgroundImage = new Image("src/com/warstrike/graphics/resources/2d-game-background-6.jpg", 1366, 1000, false, true);
        BackgroundImage background =  new BackgroundImage(backgroundImage, BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT, null);
        mainPane.setBackground(new Background(background));
    }//end createBackground function

//end class

    public Scene drawImageOnScreen(double x, double y, double rotation, String imagePath) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        //Creating an image 
          Image image1 = new Image(new FileInputStream(imagePath));  

          //Setting the image view 
          ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image1); 

          //Setting the position of the image 
          imageView.setX(x); 
          imageView.setY(y); 
          imageView.setRotate(rotation);

          //setting the fit height and width of the image view 
          imageView.setFitHeight(x); 
          imageView.setFitWidth(y); 

          //Setting the preserve ratio of the image view 
          imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

          Group root = new Group(imageView);  

          //Creating a scene object 
          Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 500);  

          return scene;


    }//end drawImageOnScreen function

}
```

I'm not sure how do I proceed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You managed to add the buttons to your scene. What's different to `ImageView`s? Why is using a similar approach not working for you? Or are you asking for a tutorial explaining to you how to write a basic game. This would be too broad.

Comment: I'm not sure if the same implementation for the buttons can be used to add "tank" sprites as well. Also I followed a tutorial on YouTube on adding buttons which I don't really understand what the code does, hence I'm not too sure where to start.